# Вызов Materialize.toast() с php-кода

Tags: php, javascript

Можно ли вызвать js-функцию с фреймворка MaterializeCSS из php-кода?
Пытаюсь сделать по аналогии с alert(), но не выходит..

```
if($condition)
{
    //echo "<script>alert('foo')</script>";
    echo "<script>Materialize.toast('bar')</script>";
}
```

Comment: Он вам нужен при загрузке страницы? Если да, то 

    <script>Materialize.toast('bar')</script>

Добавьте в самый конец кода страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего ваше решение не работает из-за того, что вызов Materialize.toast('bar') работает с DOM, а DOM еще не готов. Для решения задачи нужно дождаться готовности DOM дерева и затем запустить ваш код.

native js решение

```
<?php if ($condition) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onDomReady() {
            Materialize.toast('bar')
        }
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDomReady);
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
echo "<script>$(document).ready(function() { Materialize.toast('bar') });</script>";
```

Comment: Автор не добавил jQuery тег в вопрос. Поэтому скорее всего ему нужно решение на чистом js

Comment: @kison, насколько я знаю, jQuery "вшит" в Materialize

Comment: http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html#setup, в мануале они подключают jquery отдельно, поэтому полагаю что ваше суждение может быть неверным.

Comment: Но то, что Materialize не работает без jquery это факт )